# Get all following dates in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with these rows:

```
DATE START |     DATE END
2010-04-01 |    2018-09-30
2018-10-01 |    2019-02-13
2019-02-14 |    2019-07-24
2019-12-30 |    2020-01-31
```

I want to get this result:

```
DATE START |     DATE END
2010-04-01 |    2019-07-24
2019-12-30 |    2020-01-31
```

That's mean I need to get all following dates. Who are next one to date end of previous row.
This is used in application to calculate work experience of employee in company.
Is there any way to do this without using CURSOR, WHILE,...
Just using things from SQL like temporary tables, cte, update, select, delete,...

Comment: you can do that using `recursive cte` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions

Comment: @Squirrel yeah I know that but I have zero experience with recursive cte, I was trying to do that but I haven't success. Do you have some advice for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  Use `lag()` to get the previous end.  And then a cumulative sum and aggregation:

```
select min(date_start), max(date_end)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_date_end >= dateadd(day, -1, date_start)
                      then 0 else 1
                 end) over (order by date_start) as grp
      from (select t.*, lag(date_end) over (order by date_start) as prev_date_end
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp;
```